# Pull and display more data while using accounts-facebook

Tags: meteor

I've tried pulling more data from facebook while using accounts-ui + facebook
but for some reason I'm not able to pull/display the data
I've tried editing facebook_server.js to pull email and age with no success in addition tried adding Meteor.loginWithFacebook function and still no luck
Could anyone attach an example how to do it properly?

Answer (score 1):

This answer might help, although it's using the Github service and not facebook. But the flow should be the same.

[Meteor login with external service: how to get profile information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660219/meteor-login-with-external-service-how-to-get-profile-information/13870972#13870972)