# Meteor login with external service: how to get profile information?

Tags: facebook, meteor, github, twitter, authentication

I use the Accounts-UI and Accounts-[Github/Twitter/Facebook/Google] packages which allows login with external service.

I modified `Accounts.ui.config` with `requestPermissions`, example:

```
Accounts.ui.config({
  requestPermissions: {
    github: ['user'],
    facebook: ['user_photos']
  }
});
```

But when I logged me with Github (for example), I get only my Github's name.

Same thing with others external services.

How to get more information, like the url of the profile picture?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the Accounts.onCreateUser(fn) method to customize what gets stored when the user is created. Here is some sample code:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
  var accessToken = user.services.github.accessToken,
      result,
      profile;

  result = Meteor.http.get("https://api.github.com/user", {
    params: {
      access_token: accessToken
    }
  });

  if (result.error)
    throw result.error;

  profile = _.pick(result.data,
    "login",
    "name",
    "avatar_url",
    "url",
    "company",
    "blog",
    "location",
    "email",
    "bio",
    "html_url");

  user.profile = profile;

  return user;
});
```

You have to make an additional call to the service in the callback function to grab any additional attributes. Currently, there's no way that I know of to plug directly into the method that Meteor uses to get the identity attributes.

Comment: Wow that was really helpful, thanks mate. But I wonder how were you able to find the "user.services.github.accessToken" thing ?

Comment: I just looked at the mongo document that was created. I don't think it's documented.

Comment: Also, there's a screencast I did on this here: http://www.eventedmind.com/posts/meteor-customizing-login

Comment: This is so good, would you happen to be knowledgeable also about how this would look like with Twitter? I've tried to port over to no avail so far. (even have my own question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22227091/meteor-twitter-accounts-bio-and-avatar)