# Accounts.OnCreateUser() not firing

Tags: meteor

I'm following this fantastic tutorial on customizing login found as the answer on this post - http://goo.gl/VLO34 - but it's not working for me.

I copied all the files verbatim, and even added supplementary smart packages such as underscore `_.pick`, and http `Meteor.http.get` just in case it was required, and mistakenly left out.

Anyhoo - I get github to authorize my app, but Meteor.users in the web console and `db.users.findOne()` on the local mongo instance show that `Accounts.OnCreateUser()` didn't add any new information to my user profile [that I'm pulling in from github]. In other words, `{{currentUser.profile.avatar_url}}` and `{{currentUser.profile.login}}` won't reveal anything following that tutorial. So I get blank info on the screen.

I tried that screencasts first attempt, and noticed that `{loginButtons}}` returns values for `{{currentUser.profile.login}}`. I've reviewed the code many times for typos, but feel that something is quite off with `Accounts.onCreateUser(fn)`...

I'm using Meteor 0.5.7, and if anyone else has experienced this problem following that screencast, please let me know. Thanks,

EDIT: I've deployed the project to - http://rptest-customlogin.meteor.com/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Author of the screencast here. And as of a few seconds ago, a new user on your site :-). So, it  looks like login is working on your site. But I'm guessing what's happening in your app is the login info isn't available yet at the time of rendering or at the time you're printing to the console. The reason is that all of that info is being populated asynchronously. It takes a few seconds for the process to complete. If you're relying on Meteor.user().profile data in your templates you need to check first if the login process is still underway.

To do that, you can use either the `Meteor.loggingIn()` javascript function or the `{{#if loggingIn}}` handlebars block helper. That function is "reactive" which means once the result changes from `true` to `false` your UI will update. So the template might look something like this:

```
<template name="loginDependentWidget">
  {{#if loggingIn}}
     Logging In
  {{else}}
     {{currentUser.profile.avatar_url}}
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

Does this help?

Comment: Your suggestion makes sense, helps me learn more about the framework, but ultimately sparked the answer to my question - I had a typo on {{#if logginIn}}, which should have been {{#if loggingIn}} - missed a g. I think I was going off the user_logginin :) Thanks very much for everyone who's spent time troubleshooting with me! It now works!

Comment: I make that mistake all the time. I even made it when posting my response here! It can be a little confusing when Handlebars just returns an empty string if a method isn't defined.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a typo but `Accounts.OnCreateUser(fn);` should be `Accounts.onCreateUser(fn);`
Meteor docs: http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_oncreateuser

And then another post on the same subject:
[Meteor login with external service: how to get profile information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660219/meteor-login-with-external-service-how-to-get-profile-information)

EDIT:
Posting as edit due the formatting of the below piece of code.
In the meantime I have got it running on my own project with this piece of code:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
       if(!options || !user) {
        console.log('error creating user');
        return;
    } else {
        if(options.profile) {
            user.profile = options.profile;
        }
    }
    return user;
});
```

Which is working just fine. Have you placed the `Accounts.onCreateUser();` on the server?

Comment: That was a typo - and the shortened url in my description is the same post you linked - I literally copied that file to reduce grammatical errors. Here's the link at the end of that post to the screencast - http://www.eventedmind.com/posts/meteor-customizing-login. I'll keep hunting for grammatical errors, but at this time, only {{currentUser.profile}} is blank.

Comment: Accounts.onCreateUser() is within the server directory.

Comment: Martin, I tried your version as well, and would love to give some sort of credit - but ultimately, I don't get how assigning user.profile to options.profile would get me ExternalService credentials, like avatar_url? Cmather makes a call to the github api, passing in access tokens, and copies the necessary credentials over to the profile variable, which is then assigned to the user.profile. I'd love to learn more about what your thought process was, and doubly confirm if it did actually work for you as you stated.