# How do I properly incorporate external login services to Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I want to add Facebook, Twitter, and Google login services with Meteor. It seems easy enough to do so, but where I get lost is customizing the user document so that it's inline with standard user accounts. For example, using FB it stores all the profile fields in services:

I'm aware that I'm supposed to use Accounts.onCreateUser() to normalize the user document before it's saved into the database, but I'm lacking a good example. I saw the github one here:

[Meteor login with external service: how to get profile information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660219/meteor-login-with-external-service-how-to-get-profile-information)

But I'm having trouble grasping it. So for example if I have Facebook, Twitter, and Google, in my server-side onCreateUser function:

1. How do I get all services to follow this layout:

   ```
   {

       "_id" : "RERDDXHyhob8Ypqht",
       "createdAt" : ISODate("2014-03-03T18:47:57.455Z"),
       "emails" : [
               {
                       "address" : "persons@gmail.com",
                       "verified" : false
               }
       ],
       "profile" : {
               "firstname" : "John",
               "lastname" : "Doe",
               "user_status" : "new user"
       },
       "services" : {
               "email" : {
                       "verificationTokens" : [
                               {
                                       "token" : "z8yAhnpJotpiBWqh3",
                                       "address" : "some@email.com",
                                       "when" : ISODate("2014-03-03T18:47:57.475Z")
                               }
                       ]
               },
               "password" : {
                       "reset" : {
                               "token" : "Q48WBZvx9m4onMtky",
                               "email" : "some@email.com",
                               "when" : ISODate("2014-03-03T18:55:40.955Z")
                       },
                       "srp" : {
                               "identity" : "asdfadsfadsfasdf",
                               "salt" : "adsfadsfasdfasdf",
                               "verifier" : "asdfadsfadsfasdff8e6c"
                       }
               },
               "resume" : {
                       "loginTokens" : [ ]
               }
       },
       "username" : "some@email.com"
   ```

   }

So here is some dummy logic to explain what I'm trying to do:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
    // If using email/standard account creation use default hook.
         if (options.profile) {
         user.profile = options.profile;
         user.profile.user_status = "new user";
       }
       return user;

    // We detect Facebook being used for authentication...
       Grab facebook stuff and organize it so that it follows my above example. Like, all those profile fields embedded in services.facebook is fine, but can I copy them so that I can put profile: { firstname: firstnamefromfacebook, lastname: lastnamefromfacebook, etc.

    // We detect Google, or twitter, and you get where I'm going with this.


});
```

I also looked at an interesting article here:

http://ondrej-kvasnovsky.blogspot.com/2013/07/meteor-how-to-login-with-github-account.html

It looks a bit clunky, but maybe necessary. I'd like to also incorporate this same type of logic in my system so that if it finds the user already exists it handles it properly. Also in that case, what security problems can arise? Does it need to do an email verification first? I guess Facebook takes care of that by verifying their email on that end?

I want to prevent people from having two accounts...

a. John creates an account by filling out the form.
b. Later John signs in with Facebook

I want to figure out the best way to merge these two accounts.

I think this is my last stumbling block on my authentication system. Great examples that perhaps I didn't find would be wonderful. Or if you've done this, if you can share so the rest of us newbies can get a head start.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: "So here is some dummy logic to explain what I'm trying to do:" So...what is your actual problem? Does that logic not suffice?

Comment: The problem is I can't figure out how to programmatically incorporate the dummy logic.

Comment: Which part? All you need to do is return the `user` document you want stored in the db.

Comment: I'm not understanding how to rearrange the document structure based on which services is being used to authenticated. Also, once they're created, what happens next time they click FB login for example? Does the onCreateUser look for their account first and sign them in or do I have to build that?

Comment: Why are you attempting to do this? Just have some standard default user/profile settings and extend them to the user. I suggest actually playing with these services first and you'll quickly see how they work.

Comment: I'm wanting to use handlebar helpers that are standardized so that currentUser.profile.firstname works for everyone, and when someone signs in with FB it stores those profile field within services instead of profile options. I have a custom sign-up form for regular users with Firstname, Lastname, and some other stuff... So I'm just lost it seems. I don't know what you mean. Go easy on me. 2 weeks/less into Meteor.

Comment: Pseudocode. `if facebook then user.username = FB.services.username; if google then user.username = google.services.username; return user;`

Comment: Thanks Brad. Will hack away at this and report back. I appreciate your help.